# setLocation in actionPerformed change button location only if there are no integer incrementation

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, actionevent

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class SimpleGUI3 implements ActionListener  {
    JButton button;
    private int numClick;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleGUI3 gui = new SimpleGUI3();
        gui.go();
    }

    public void go() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        button = new JButton("Click me.");
        button.addActionListener(this);
        frame.getContentPane().add(button);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        button.setLocation(100, 100); //This code do not change the button location if numClick++ (next row) used.   
        numClick++;                   //If comment numClick++ the button changes location on click. Why location doesn't changes if this row uncomment?
        button.setText("Has been clicked " + numClick + " times.");
    }
}
```

The question is: 
Why location changes on click without numClick++ in code and why the button ocation doesn't changes if numClick++ work in code?

Comment: `button.setLocation(100, 100);` Don't do that. It is effectively fighting the layout manager. What is the purpose of moving the button?

Comment: The purpose is just understanding how it works. With commented nubClick++ the button moves on click, once.

Comment: *"The purpose is just understanding how it works."* So.. you want to understand how something that shouldn't be done, works? Utterly pointless. **If** there were an actual reason to move components on button click, it would best be done by changing the parameters of an `EmptyBorder` that wraps a panel containing the component. But instead turn your attention to things that are actually useful & maintain best practices..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you change the value of numClick the text of the button also changes when you use the `setText()` method.

When a property of the button changes then Swing will automatically invoked `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the component.

The `revalidate()` will invoke the layout manager and the layout manager will reset the location of the button back to (0, 0) based on the rules of the layout manager, which is a BorderLayout by default for the content pane of the frame.

Bottom line is don't try to manage the location or size of a component. That is the job of the layout manager.

Also, learn and use Java naming conventions. Class names should start with an upper case character.

Read the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for Swing basics.